# Not evaluating logarithms with a float as base

Tags: python, python-2.7, sympy

As you can see in the following example, SymPy evaluates logarithms if the base is not an integer.

```
IPython console for SymPy 1.0 (Python 2.7.10-64-bit) (ground types: python)

These commands were executed:
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')
>>> k, m, n = symbols('k m n', integer=True)
>>> f, g, h = symbols('f g h', cls=Function)
>>> init_printing()

In [1]: log(4, 3)
Out[1]: 
log(4)
──────
log(3)


In [2]: log(4, 1/2)
Out[2]: -1.44269504088896⋅log(4)  <<< What I get
```

What I want:

```
 log(4)
────────
log(1/2)
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a SymPy `Rational`, not a `float`:

```
log(4, Rational(1, 2))
```